# KStream-KStream inner join throws java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

In the process method of `@StreamListener`, I am mapping school KStream to person KStream and via .through() method to populate a topic "person" from which I generate a `KStream` inside another process1 method of
`@StreamListener`.

**MianApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaStreamsTableJoin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaStreamsTableJoin.class, args);
    }

    @EnableBinding(KStreamProcessorX.class)
    public static class KStreamToTableJoinApplication {

        @StreamListener
        public void process(@Input("school") KStream<SchoolKey, School> schools) {  

            schools.map((schoolKey, school) -> {
                return KeyValue.pair(new PersonKey("Adam", "Smith", schoolKey.getId()), new Person(12));
            })
            .through("person", Produced.with(new PersonKeySerde(), new PersonSerde()));
        }

        @StreamListener
        public void process1(@Input("school_1") KStream<SchoolKey, School> schools, @Input("person") KStream<PersonKey, Person> persons) {

            schools.selectKey((schoolKey, school) -> schoolKey.getId())
                    .join(persons.selectKey((personKey, person) -> personKey.getId()),
                            (school, person) -> {
                                System.out.println("school_app2= " + school + ", person_app2= " + person);
                                return null;
                            },
                            JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(1)),
                            Joined.with(Serdes.Integer(), new SchoolSerde(), new PersonSerde())
                    );
        }
    }

    interface KStreamProcessorX {

        @Input("person")
        KStream<?, ?> inputPersonKStream();

        @Input("school")
        KStream<?, ?> inputSchoolKStream();

        @Input("school_1")
        KStream<?, ?> inputSchool1KStream();

    }
}
```

Inside the method process1, this KStream need to join with another KStream but I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "stream-join-sample_2-654e8060-5b29-4694-9188-032a9779529c-StreamThread-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: class kafka.streams.join.School cannot be cast to class kafka.streams.join.Person (kafka.streams.join.School and kafka.streams.join.Person are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.AbstractStream.lambda$reverseJoiner$0(AbstractStream.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKStreamJoin$KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKStreamJoin.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamJoinWindow$KStreamJoinWindowProcessor.process(KStreamJoinWindow.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:199)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:420)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:889)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:804)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:773)
```

I think this exception is related to incorrect serde's but I can't figure out which serde's are creating the problem and how to fix it. Or is it that during mapping in method process,
re-partitioning is triggered and this has something to do with incorrect serde's?

POJO's and Serde's:

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

    private double age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(double age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @JsonGetter("age")
    public double getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @JsonSetter("age")
    public void setAge(double age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**PersonSerde.java**

```
public class PersonSerde extends Serdes.WrapperSerde<Person> {
    public PersonSerde () {
        super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Person.class));
    }
}
```

**PersonKey.java**

```
public class PersonKey {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int id;

    public PersonKey() {
    }

    public PersonKey(String firstName, String lastName, int id) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonGetter("firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @JsonSetter("firstName")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @JsonGetter("lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @JsonSetter("lastName")
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @JsonGetter("id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonSetter("id")
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PersonKey{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PersonKey personKey = (PersonKey) o;
        return id == personKey.id &&
                Objects.equals(firstName, personKey.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(lastName, personKey.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName, id);
    }
}
```

**PersonKeySerde.java**

```
public class PersonKeySerde extends Serdes.WrapperSerde<PersonKey> {
    public PersonKeySerde () {
        super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(PersonKey.class));
    }
}
```

serde's and pojo's for School class is similar to Person class.

application.yml

```
spring.application.name: stream-join-sample

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.school:
  destination: school
  contentType: application/json
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.school:
  consumer:
    keySerde: kafka.streams.serde.SchoolKeySerde
    valueSerde: kafka.streams.serde.SchoolSerde
    application-id: stream-join-sample_1

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.person:
  destination: person
  contentType: application/json
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.person:
  consumer:
    keySerde: kafka.streams.serde.PersonKeySerde
    valueSerde: kafka.streams.serde.PersonSerde
    application-id: stream-join-sample_2

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.school_1:
  destination: school
  contentType: application/json
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.school_1:
  consumer:
    keySerde: kafka.streams.serde.SchoolKeySerde
    valueSerde: kafka.streams.serde.SchoolSerde
    application-id: stream-join-sample_2

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
  brokers: localhost
  configuration:
    default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    commit.interval.ms: 100
```

[image: set a brekpoint at KStreamKStreamJoin.java:94]

[image: StateStoreSerde]

[Sample Application](https://github.com/arslanakhtar61/kafkaStreamJoin) with reproducible steps:

[image: MeteredWindowStore_debug1]
[image: MeteredWindowStore_debug2]
[image: MeteredWindowStore_debug3]
[image: MeteredWindowStore_debug4]

Comment: Maybe set a brekpoint at `KStreamKStreamJoin.java:94` to see where the data comes from?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the response. I have added a screenshot of the debug window at the breakpoint for your review. Also I have added the [link](https://github.com/arslanakhtar61/kafkaStreamJoin) for the sample application with reproducible steps.

Comment: Seem the first argument of the `join` call (`value`) is of type `School` was should be correct. So the iterator would return a `School` but not a `Person` -- question is why? What types are the `StateStoreSerde` ?

Comment: I have added another screenshot of an expanded serde section of debug window. Its Key Serde: IntergerSerde and Value Serde: JsonSerde<>(School.class) I think

Comment: I agree. So it used the wrong `Serde`. What I am wondering is, why the deserization does not fail for this case (but I am not JSON expert)? Let's track this down. Please set a breakpoint in `MeteredWindowStore#initStoreSerde()` and see where the `Serde` comes from -- I _think_ that `MeteredWindowStore#valueSerde` should not be `null` but should be a `PersonSerde` because you set `PersonSerde` explicitly via `Joined.with` -- if this is not the case, check the constructor of `MeteredWindowStore` to see why the incorrect serde if passed into `MeteredWindowStore`.

Comment: I have added the debug screenshots (in order of debugging before the exception is thrown). It appears that the `MeteredWindowStore#valueSerde` takes both `SchoolSerde` and `PersonSerde` during processing and it never becomes null. I am not sure if the order of serde assignment is important here like now the constructor is called twice with the 1st time `SchoolSerde` and then the 2nd time with `PersonSerde`. Same order follows with init method being called twice with first `SchoolSerde` and then `PersonSerde`. Should it have been the other way around or it doesn't matter? Thanks

Comment: This sounds all correct. The join is using two windowed stores, one for left and one for right hand side. And it seems that both get configured with the correct serdes. I downloaded your code from Github to dig into this, and I believe it's actually a bug in the used JsonSerdes. The type is encoded in record headers, but headers are never cleaned up -- this result in a case for which two different types are encoded and one is picked "randomly" when reading data from a topic -- and it picks the wrong one.

Comment: As a workaround, you can replace `selectKey()` with a `transform()` and clear the header within `transform()`... It's a hack though. You should file a ticket agains SpringBoot project.

Comment: Thanks Alot @MatthiasJ.Sax. For now as a workaround, I am applying `selectKey()` before calling `through()` during message production to upload messages to topic so that we don't have to use `selectKey()` during message consumption as the keys from both KStreams already matches. This however makes the topic not very re-usable as the messages contains more specific keys. I will try using your suggestion to `transform()` and clear the header and also raise a ticket for fixing the bug. Appreciate all your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your code from GitHub to dig into this, and turns out it's actually a bug in the used `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer`. The type (`School`, `Person`, `PersonKey`, `SchoolKey`) is encoded in the record headers, but the headers are never cleaned up. Each time the type changes, just a new header is appended (header keys are not unique, and duplicates are allowed).

For some record, the same type is just encoded multiple times, and thus, this part of the code works. However, for some cases, different types are encoded and one type (the first header found) is picked "randomly" when reading data from a topic. The happens before the join, but when receiving data from a repartition topic. If the wrong type is picked, the code crashed with a `ClassCastException` later.

**New Answer:**

Following the discussion on this ticket, https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/685, you should disable that type information is written into the record headers via:

```java
props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
```

Note, that all `Serdes` that are created manually, ie, via calling `new` must be configured manually:

```java
Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);

PersonKeySerde personKeySerde = new PersonKeySerde();
personKeySerde.configure(config, true);

PersonSerde personSerde = new PersonSerde();
personSerde.configure(config, false);

// ...
.through("person", Produced.with(personKeySerde, personSerde));
```

**Original Answer:**

As a workaround, you can replace `map` and `selectKey()` with a `transform()` and clear the headers within `transform()`. It's a hack though. You should file a ticket agains SpringBoot project so they can fix `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer`.

The following code removes the headers and ensure that the correct types are used, avoiding the `ClassCastException`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaStreamJoinApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaStreamJoinApplication.class, args);
    }

    @EnableBinding(KStreamProcessorX.class)
    public static class KafkaKStreamJoinApplication {

        @StreamListener
        public void process(@Input("school") KStream<SchoolKey, School> schools) {
            // replace map() with transform()
            schools.transform(new TransformerSupplier<SchoolKey, School, KeyValue<PersonKey, Person>>() {
                @Override
                public Transformer<SchoolKey, School, KeyValue<PersonKey, Person>> get() {
                    return new Transformer<SchoolKey, School, KeyValue<PersonKey, Person>>() {
                        ProcessorContext context;

                        @Override
                        public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
                            this.context = context;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public KeyValue<PersonKey, Person> transform(final SchoolKey key, final School value) {
                            // clear all headers; would be sufficient to only remove type header
                            for (Header h : context.headers().toArray()) {
                                context.headers().remove(h.key());
                            }
                            // same a "old" map code:
                            return KeyValue.pair(new PersonKey("Adam", "Smith", key.getId()), new Person(12));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void close() {}
                    };
                }})
                .through("person", Produced.with(new PersonKeySerde(), new PersonSerde()));
        }

        @StreamListener
        public void process1(@Input("school_1") KStream<SchoolKey, School> schools, @Input("person") KStream<PersonKey, Person> persons) {

            // replace selectKey() with transform()
            schools.transform(new TransformerSupplier<SchoolKey, School, KeyValue<Integer, School>>() {
                @Override
                public Transformer<SchoolKey, School, KeyValue<Integer, School>> get() {
                    return new Transformer<SchoolKey, School, KeyValue<Integer, School>>() {
                        ProcessorContext context;

                        @Override
                        public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
                            this.context = context;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public KeyValue<Integer, School> transform(final SchoolKey key, final School value) {
                            // clear all headers; would be sufficient to only remove type header
                            for (Header h : context.headers().toArray()) {
                                context.headers().remove(h.key());
                            }
                            // effectively the same as "old" selectKey code:
                            return KeyValue.pair(key.getId(), value);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void close() {}
                    };
                }})
                // replace selectKey() with transform()
                .join(persons.transform(new TransformerSupplier<PersonKey, Person, KeyValue<Integer, Person>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Transformer<PersonKey, Person, KeyValue<Integer, Person>> get() {
                        return new Transformer<PersonKey, Person, KeyValue<Integer, Person>>() {
                            ProcessorContext context;

                            @Override
                            public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
                                this.context = context;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public KeyValue<Integer, Person> transform(final PersonKey key, final Person value) {
                                // clear all headers; would be sufficient to only remove type header
                                for (Header h : context.headers().toArray()) {
                                    context.headers().remove(h.key());
                                }
                                // effectively same as "old" selectKey code:
                                return KeyValue.pair(key.getId(), value);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void close() {}
                        };
                    }}),
                    (school, person) -> {
                        System.out.println("school_app2= " + school + ", person_app2= " + person);
                        return null;
                    },
                    JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(1)),
                    Joined.with(Serdes.Integer(), new SchoolSerde(), new PersonSerde())
                );
        }
    }

    interface KStreamProcessorX {
        @Input("person")
        KStream<?, ?> inputPersonKStream();

        @Input("school")
        KStream<?, ?> inputSchoolKStream();

        @Input("school_1")
        KStream<?, ?> inputSchool1KStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm - the type headers are now removed by the deserializer, by default, [since Spring for Apache Kafka version 2.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/797). So I am not sure what's going on here, yet.

Comment: I confirmed in the debugger that the headers are removed. I also disabled the type headers altogether in his app, and we still get the class cast exception. See [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/685#issuecomment-504463248).

Comment: Seems that @muhammad-arslan-akhtar is using `2.1.5.RELEASE` though: https://github.com/arslanakhtar61/kafkaStreamJoin

Comment: That's the boot release, boot 2.1.5 pulls in spring-kafka 2.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there are some stale data somewhere in the topics or in the underlying changelog topics? Can you try to use new topics and different application-id's to see if it fixes your issues?

Here is a sample configuration to use:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.school:
  destination: school-abc
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.school:
  consumer:
    keySerde: kafka.streams.serde.SchoolKeySerde
    valueSerde: kafka.streams.serde.SchoolSerde
    application-id: stream-join-sample_diff_id_1

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.person:
  destination: person-abc
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.person:
  consumer:
    keySerde: kafka.streams.serde.PersonKeySerde
    valueSerde: kafka.streams.serde.PersonSerde
    application-id: stream-join-sample_diff_id_2

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.school_1:
  destination: school-abc
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.school_1:
  consumer:
    keySerde: kafka.streams.serde.SchoolKeySerde
    valueSerde: kafka.streams.serde.SchoolSerde
    application-id: stream-join-sample_diff_id_2

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
  brokers: localhost
  configuration:
    default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    commit.interval.ms: 100
```

Note that I changed the topic names, application id etc. You might want to update any producers that populate the topics.

Also, notice that you don't need to specify the content type, setting `useNativeDecoding` to `false` etc. since those are the defaults in the current version of the kafka streams binder.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried re-running the whole zookeeper, kafka again by cleaning everything and using your yml but the same exception is still showing up. Also I have added the [link](https://github.com/arslanakhtar61/kafkaStreamJoin) for the sample application with the reproducible steps. Appreciate if you could try giving it a run. Thanks